# Selenium-Firefox Driver Issue (Firefox Driver cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to write simple selenium scripts  using maven ,But getting an error with firefox driver despite downloading all the dependent selenium jars through maven.

Refer the screenshot below: Any help is deeply appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOFUD.png)

Comment: 'getting an error' what is that. Also instead of adding image, paste the code here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: as per the image, you are not saved some of the changes. You can try to save. It may resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
public class NewTest {

     public WebDriver driver;

     @BeforeClass
      public void setupClass() {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\***\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\geckodriver.exe");
         driver =  new FirefoxDriver();

      }

      @Test
      public void openMyBlog() {
            driver.get("http://www.google.com");
            System.out.println("This is first test");
      }


      @AfterClass
      public void tearDownClass() {
      // driver.quit();
      }

    }
```

Make sure you have imported all required packages.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;  
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
```